# CA Certificate request failure - The RPC server is unavailable - DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer

Tags: iis-7, certificate, dcom

I am facing an issue while trying to **request user certificate** from a Microsoft CA on **IIS7/Windows Server 2008 R2**.

For requesting certificate, I am using the [CCertRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385054%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) submit method.

In my logs, I have the following error :

```
CCertRequest::Submit: The RPC server is unavailable. 0x800706ba (WIN32: 1722) COMException    at CERTCLIENTLib.CCertRequestClass.Submit(Int32 Flags, String strRequest, String strAttributes, String strConfig)
```

and the associated DCOM error in Event Viewer :

> DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer
>   cert.XXX.com/XXXCA using any of the configured
>   protocols.

When I ping the CA using CertUtil command tools, the command is successfully :

> C:\Windows\system32>certutil  -ping -config "cert.XXX.com\XXXCA "
>   Connecting to cert.XXX.com\XXXCA ... Server "XXXCA"
>   ICertRequest2 interface is alive
>   CertUtil: -ping command completed successfully.

Do you have any idea to help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it!

The valid configuration string for the Certificate Services server is

> ComputerName\CAName

and not

> ComputerName/CAName